# How to obtain ES6 module of React and ReactDOM?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am not intending to use WebPack bundled js file, instead, to `import` React ES6 modules natively in ES6 way.

Here's the typical code in JSX, or TSX, or just ES6.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

So, I investigated `./node_modules/react` and `react-dom`.

There are 2 directories named `cjs` and `umd`, and each contain `react.development.js` and `react.production.min.js`.

Fair enough, so investigating files,

`cjs` is for CommonJS `module.exports` /require module.

`umd` is Universal Module Definition, and looks like to be used via Babel plugin `transform-es2015-modules-umd`.

In either files, they are not ES6 modules, and to me it's very awkward situation not to be able to find module files for:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

How to obtain ES6 module of React and ReactDOM??

Is there any method to generate ES6 modules using a tool in the eco of Babel or even TypeScript?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can build the library on your own using the source code to any module definition you like.

Comment: Have you tried hosting `react.production.min.js` in the same directory tree of your webserver as the module that imports it? And the use the correct path: `import React from '../path/to/react/react.production.min.js';`

Comment: @Shilly Actually, no. Since I didn't feel trying for nothing, instead, I simply searched the source text with `export`, the result is none. Anyway, thanks guys.

Answer (score 9):

**2021-04-11 update:**

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11503#issuecomment-662647468 is an update from 2020-07-22 from Dan Abramov that mentions the new https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html. With the new transform, there is a lot less reason to import the default export of React.

Actual first party React ESM being distributed might happen after React 17 drops.

> In addition to cleaning up unused imports, this will also help you prepare for a future major version of React (not React 17) which will support ES Modules and not have a default export.

**Older answer**

On November 9th, 2017 [Dan Abramov said](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11503):

> Currently we only ship CommonJS versions of all packages. However we might want to ship them as ESM in the future (#10021).
>
> We can't quite easily do this because we haven't really decided on what top-level ES exports would look like from each package. For example, does react have a bunch of named exports, but also a default export called React? Should we encourage people to import * for better tree shaking? What about react-test-renderer/shallow that currently exports a class (and thus would start failing in Node were it converted to be a default export)?

[The issue referenced above](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10021) is a request for what you're asking for from June 21, 2017.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a fairly simple, but hacky, solution while we wait for an official React ESM. Use the umd modules which ship with the npm package of React and ReactDOM. Wrap the umd modules in the following way:

React

```
let g = {}

let w = (function(){
// Standard umd module code goes here
}).bind(g)

w()

export default g.React
```

ReactDOM

```
import React from './react'

let g = {React: React}

let w = (function(){
// Standard umd module code goes here
}).bind(g)

w()

export default g.ReactDOM
```

You may need to modify the the `./react` import path to work with what your server expects.